# dynamic jpg urls with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to dynamically serve images to web pages with htaccess based on the filename in the url. Normally, I use a nested directory structure throughout my website to serve a dynamic url based on the pseudo directory names. In this case, I would just like to query the file name (sans extension) and serve it to a PHP script so that:

```
/images/foo.jpg
```

becomes

```
/images/index.php?image=foo
```

while also let existing jpg images in this directory be served. I am sure it is easy, as I have been able to accomplish some pretty cool things with htaccess, but just not this one yet. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "while also let existing jpg images in this directory be served"? Does that mean that foo.jpg doesn't exist and should be redirected to index.php but images that do exist in /images/ should just be served as they would normally?

Comment: exactly. i need to create 'phantom' jpgs that get fed from php and let the originals exist as they do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /images/index.php?image=$1 [NC,L]
```

note: if you need the extension you use `$2`

Comment: this works when the file exists, but when not, i get a 404... i want to be able to create 'phantom' jpgs and also serve the original files without having to pull them from php.

Comment: all the images are saved in the images folder? if you want to create a 'phantom' image it's different. I updated my ticket. Does you index.php display the correct headers for images?

Comment: no, some are and some aren't... i want to feed seo-friendly image names for my filesystem that is alphanumeric (ie. DR382U1.jpg) and is situated elsewhere.

Comment: got it, I use this rule for my site. and my index.php generates a dummy image. where is the other folder where the  images are located?